# jqGrid compatible version for jQuery-1.11.3

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, compatibility

We are using jqGrid  4.3.1 and jQuery-1.7.1.js in my project. We want to upgrade jQuery to jQuery-1.11.3 version. What is the compatible jqGrid version to use as I am getting build issues if I use the same jqGrid version(4.3.1).

Comment: looking the jqgrid repository in github, the version 1.11.0 is in use. https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/jquery.js